# Tkinter Root Window mouse drag motion becomes slower

Tags: python, tkinter

I noticed a lagging behavior when I dragged my Tkinter Root window across the screen (it does not have same motion speed as my mouse cursor). I have created a simple Tkinter app where one of the features is that user can select via button widget(s) to show/hide different Frame widgets which contains other child widgets. I have created all the required widget(s) during **init**() in a class.

In this example, lets say I have 4 Frame widgets (Frame A, B, C, D) and 4 buttons (Button A, B, C, D), respectively. Each Frame widget(s) contain several child widget(s). So, when I click Button A, the app will show Frame A using .grid(), and hide other Frame(s) using .grid_remove(). However, when I continue my clicking actions on the rest of the Button(s) to display & hide other Frame(s), I noticed it affected my Root window dragging motion when I want to move the app across my screen.

[image: Demonstration GIF]

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
from tkinter import ttk

class AppGui(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(index = 0, weight = 1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(index = 1, weight = 1)
        self.main_interface()

    def main_interface(self):
        prnt = tk.Frame(self, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0)
        self.btn_a = tk.Button(prnt, relief = tk.GROOVE, text = 'Frame A', width = 12, font='Helvetica 11 bold')
        self.btn_b = tk.Button(prnt, relief = tk.GROOVE, text = 'Frame B', width = 12, font='Helvetica 11 bold')
        self.btn_c = tk.Button(prnt, relief = tk.GROOVE, text = 'Frame C', width = 12, font='Helvetica 11 bold')
        self.btn_d = tk.Button(prnt, relief = tk.GROOVE, text = 'Frame D', width = 12, font='Helvetica 11 bold')
        self.btn_a['command'] = partial(self.fr_sel_func, 'A')
        self.btn_b['command'] = partial(self.fr_sel_func, 'B')
        self.btn_c['command'] = partial(self.fr_sel_func, 'C')
        self.btn_d['command'] = partial(self.fr_sel_func, 'D')

        self.btn_a.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (1,5), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')
        self.btn_b.grid(column = 1, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (1,5), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')
        self.btn_c.grid(column = 2, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (1,5), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')
        self.btn_d.grid(column = 3, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (1,1), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')

        self.hashmap_fr_gui = {}
        # self.create_fr_gui(): Function to create a Frame widget with all the child widgets.
        # Store the Frame widget(s) in a hashmap
        self.hashmap_fr_gui['A'] = self.create_fr_gui('A')
        self.hashmap_fr_gui['B'] = self.create_fr_gui('B') 
        self.hashmap_fr_gui['C'] = self.create_fr_gui('C') 
        self.hashmap_fr_gui['D'] = self.create_fr_gui('D')

        prnt.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (2,1), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')

        self.btn_a.invoke()

    def fr_sel_func(self, hashmap_id):
       if hashmap_id in self.hashmap_fr_gui:
           for kw, tk_gui in self.hashmap_fr_gui.items():
               if kw == hashmap_id:
                   tk_gui.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (2,2), pady = (3,1), sticky = 'nwse')
               else:
                   tk_gui.grid_remove()

    def create_fr_gui(self, hashmap_id):
        # Create Parent Frame GUI
        prnt_gui = tk.Frame(self)
        prnt_gui['bg'] = 'white'
        prnt_gui.grid_columnconfigure(index = 0, weight = 1)
        prnt_gui.grid_columnconfigure(index = 1, weight = 1)
        prnt_gui.grid_rowconfigure(index = 0, weight = 1)
        prnt_gui.grid_rowconfigure(index = 1, weight = 1)

        child_gui_a = self.create_fr_child(prnt_gui, 'Subframe 1{}'.format(hashmap_id))
        child_gui_b = self.create_fr_child(prnt_gui, 'Subframe 2{}'.format(hashmap_id))
        child_gui_c = self.create_fr_child(prnt_gui, 'Subframe 3{}'.format(hashmap_id))
        child_gui_d = self.create_fr_child(prnt_gui, 'Subframe 4{}'.format(hashmap_id))

        child_gui_a.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (1,1), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')
        child_gui_b.grid(column = 1, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (3,1), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')
        child_gui_c.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (1,1), pady = (3,1), sticky = 'nwse')
        child_gui_d.grid(column = 1, row = 1, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (3,1), pady = (3,1), sticky = 'nwse')

        return prnt_gui

    def create_fr_child(self, prnt, panel_name):
        # Create Child Frame GUI
        child_gui = tk.Frame(prnt, highlightthickness = 1, highlightbackground = 'black')

        child_gui.grid_columnconfigure(index = 0, weight = 1)
        child_gui.grid_columnconfigure(index = 1, weight = 10)

        child_gui.grid_rowconfigure(index = 0, weight = 0)
        child_gui.grid_rowconfigure(index = 1, weight = 1)

        name_tk_lb = tk.Label(child_gui, text = panel_name, font = 'Helvetica 14 bold'
            , justify = tk.LEFT, anchor = 'nw')
        name_tk_lb.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 1, padx = (5,1), pady = (5,5), sticky = 'nwse')
        #####################################################################################################################
        # Left Side Grid Widget(s)
        left_grid = tk.Frame(child_gui)
        left_grid.grid_columnconfigure(index = 0, weight = 1)
        left_grid.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (20,1), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')

        tk_lb = tk.Label(left_grid, text = 'Combobox: ', font = 'Helvetica 12 italic', width = 12
            , justify = 'left', anchor = 'w')
        tk_lb.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (1,5), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')

        ttk_cbox = ttk.Combobox(left_grid, values = [], width=13, state='readonly', font = 'Helvetica 11')
        ttk_cbox.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (1,5), pady = (5,1), sticky = 'nwse')

        ttk_cbox.unbind_class("TCombobox", "<MouseWheel>")

        tk_btn = tk.Button(left_grid, relief = tk.GROOVE, width = 10, height = 1, font = 'Helvetica 12')
        tk_btn['text'] = 'Button'

        tk_btn.grid(column = 0, row = 2, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (1,5), pady = (100,1), sticky = 'nwse')

        #####################################################################################################################
        # Right Side Grid Widget(s)
        right_grid = tk.Frame(child_gui)
        right_grid.grid_columnconfigure(index = 0, weight = 5)
        right_grid.grid_columnconfigure(index = 1, weight = 10)
        right_grid.grid_columnconfigure(index = 2, weight = 1)

        right_grid.grid(column = 1, row = 1, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (10,20), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')

        for i in range(0, 6):
            right_grid.grid_rowconfigure(index = i, weight = 1, min = 50)
            tk_lb  = tk.Label(right_grid, text = 'Scalebar {}'.format(i + 1), font = 'Helvetica 12', justify = 'right', anchor = 'ne')

            scl_var   = tk.StringVar()
            sbox_var  = tk.StringVar()

            tk_scl = tk.Scale(right_grid, from_=1, to=10, variable=scl_var, orient='horizontal', showvalue=0)

            tk_sbox  = tk.Spinbox(right_grid, width = 4, textvariable = sbox_var, from_=1, to=10
                                 , highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1, font = 'Helvetica 12')

            scl_var.set(1)
            tk_lb.grid(column = 0, row = i, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (3,1), pady = (3,1), sticky = 'nwes')
            tk_scl.grid(column = 1, row = i, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (3,1), pady = (4,1), sticky = 'nwe')
            tk_sbox.grid(column = 2, row = i, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (3,3), pady = (3,1), sticky = 'nwe')

        return child_gui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk_root = tk.Tk()
    tk_root_width = 890
    tk_root_height = 600
    screen_width = tk_root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = tk_root.winfo_screenheight()
    x_coordinate = int((screen_width/2) - (tk_root_width/2))
    y_coordinate = int((screen_height/2) - (tk_root_height/2))
    tk_root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(tk_root_width, tk_root_height, x_coordinate, y_coordinate))
    app_gui = AppGui(tk_root)
    tk_root.grid_columnconfigure(index = 0, weight = 1)
    tk_root.grid_rowconfigure(index = 0, weight = 1)
    app_gui.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (1,1), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')
    tk_root.mainloop()
```

The issue seem to be mitigated when i experimented with .grid_destroy() on the Frame widget(s). However, I prefer not to use .grid_destroy(), otherwise I have to re-create my widget(s) again. So to solve this issue, do I have to use .grid_remove() on every child widgets within my Frame widget(s)? Or is there any other advise/solution to this.

EDIT 1: To replicate the lagging behavior when dragging the app window, user need to click each button(s) to display each Frame widgets at least once.

Comment: Instead of displaying one frame and removing the rest every time, you can use the `.grid` method on all the frames at the start and then use the `<frame>.tkraise()` method whenever you want to show a frame. Try it out. It might reduce your problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can't run your code as-is.

Comment: Apologies @BryanOakley, I was anxious that the code might be long. The edited code above should be able to replicate the issue I am facing. I have used the same amount of widget(s) to reproduce the layout in the my main app.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The window moves around very smoothly on my OSX machine.

Comment: @BryanOakley, that is odd, on my Windows 10 desktop. After clicking each button to display each frame at least once, the movement of mouse cursor feels heavy when attempting to move the window around. During startup it does move smoothly, its only after displaying all the frames at least once it begin to slow down.

Comment: @SriramSrinivasan, I tried this approach initially as well. Using .grid method to display all the Frame widgets during app startup. Then, .lift() the appropriate frame when user clicked the corresponding buttons. However, doing this way, any attempt to drag the window around right after app startup already shows the 'slowing down' behavior.

Comment: I clicked every button dozens of times.

Comment: I am not sure what is the root causing this app behavior on my machine and I do not know how else to replicate it on your machine. I could not find any related issue on this. Could it be a memory leak? I've read some examples that memory leak can occur if widgets are constantly created on callback events. But in my case, I am reusing what I created at init(). Any thoughts on how to proceed to identify the root of the problem?

Comment: It worked form under window10. The problem is I have to figure out how to turn off each frames. I can moved window smoothly.

Comment: It worked. Actually, I don't see nothing wrong. I can clicked many times. I can moved window.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same behavior with my Tkinter app and I found out that it's caused by my mouse (SteelSeries Sensei Ten).

When I tried moving the window with a different generic mouse, the "slugish" movement was gone. Finally, I tried messing with my mouse settings and it turned out that lowering my polling rate from 1000 to 250 Hz fixes it as well.

I also found out that this behavior is dependent alongside the polling rate on the number of used widgets and the size of the window.

I guess that a better solution would be to limit the "refresh rate" of your application locally. However, I'm not sure if that's possible.

**EDIT:**
It is possible actually.

```py
from time import sleep


def on_configure(e):
    if e.widget == tk_root:
        sleep(0.015)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk_root = tk.Tk()
    tk_root.bind("<Configure>", on_configure)
    tk_root_width = 890
    tk_root_height = 600
    screen_width = tk_root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = tk_root.winfo_screenheight()
    x_coordinate = int((screen_width/2) - (tk_root_width/2))
    y_coordinate = int((screen_height/2) - (tk_root_height/2))
    tk_root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(tk_root_width, tk_root_height, x_coordinate, y_coordinate))
    app_gui = AppGui(tk_root)
    tk_root.grid_columnconfigure(index = 0, weight = 1)
    tk_root.grid_rowconfigure(index = 0, weight = 1)
    app_gui.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 1, rowspan = 1, padx = (1,1), pady = (1,1), sticky = 'nwse')
    tk_root.mainloop()
```

This fixed it for me.